# How to arrange these 5 charts in html?

Tags: html, css, google-visualization

I am using Google Chart Tools Angularjs to display 5 charts. I have problems arranging them in the manner I want. I want 4 charts in the top row and 1 chart in the second row.

To display 4 charts in the top row, the html code looks like this and it works;

```
<div google-chart chart="Chart1" style="height:300px; width:25%;float: left;"></div>
<div google-chart chart="Chart2" style="height:300px; width:25%;float: left;"></div>
<div google-chart chart="Chart3" style="height:300px; width:25%;float: left;"></div>
<div google-chart chart="Chart4" style="height:300px; width:25%;float: left;"></div>
```

My problem comes when I want to display the 5th chart in the second row. The code I used looks like this;

```
<div google-chart chart="Chart1" style="height:300px; width:25%;float: left;"></div>
<div google-chart chart="Chart2" style="height:300px; width:25%;float: left;"></div>
<div google-chart chart="Chart3" style="height:300px; width:25%;float: left;"></div>
<div google-chart chart="Chart4" style="height:300px; width:25%;float: left;"></div>
<div google-chart chart="Chart5" style="height:300px; width:25%;"></div>
```

The 5th chart cannot be seen anywhere on the webpage. How can I display the 5th chart on the next row using html?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 5th chart with the same styling

```
style="height:300px; width:25%;float: left;"
```

See [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qabay/1/edit).

Comment: Thanks for the clear example. Your answer is correct!